# How does division occur in our computers?

Tags: computers, tutorial, arithmetic-division

How does division occur inside digital computers? What is the algorithm for it?

I have searched hard in google but haven't got satisfactory results. Please provide a very clear *algorithm/flowchart* for division algorithm with a sample illustration.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but may be of interest: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/hardware-implementation-of-division-algorithm

Comment: @ Majenko that is without any answer.Also the flow chart is too complex to understand.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question will be closed.

Comment: @program-o-steve Division in an ALU is a complex operation.  You won't get a "simple" flowchart.

Comment: @ Leon Heller Oh ! [It doesn't say so](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/about) This is a pure hardware question

Comment: @ Majenko Can it be explained ?

Comment: It is off-topic according to the Faq: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @ Leon Heller I guess it isn't _...., which include electronics, physical computing..._

Comment: Division in microcontrollers is not straight forward. There are fast ways and slow ways of doing it. Slow ways are easier to understand but the fast ways are used in modern CPUs what specifically do you want to know about? Do you just want a basic understanding of the principles or a detailed analysis of modern CPUs?

Comment: @LeonHeller I usually agree with the questions you want closed, but CPU design is very much an electrical engineering question. This question could use some help to make it much more clear of what is wanted (like what konsalik is asking about) but that doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: @ Konsalik basic understanding of principles and then the detailed analysis of modern CPU's. First the slow and then we shall proceed to fast. I just need a starting point.

Answer (score 25):

Division algorithms in digital designs can be divided into two main categories. Slow division and fast division.

I suggest you read up on how binary addition and subtraction work if you are not yet familiar with these concepts.

**Slow Division**

The simplest slow methods all work in the following way: Subtract the denominator from the numerator. Do this recursively with the result of each subtraction until the remainder is less than the denominator. The amount of iterations is the integer quotient, and the amount left over is the remainder.

Example:

7/3:

1. $$7-3=4$$
2. $$4-3=1$$
3. $$1 < 3$$

Thus the answer is 2 with a remainder of 1. To make this answer a bit more relevant, here is some background. Binary subtraction via addition of the negative is performed e.g.: 7 - 3 = 7 + (-3). This is accomplished by using its two's complement. Each binary number is added using a series of full adders:

[image]

Where each 1-bit full adder gets implemented as follows:

[image]

**Fast Division**

While the slower method of division is easy to understand, it requires repetitive iterations. There exist various "fast" algorithms, but they all rely on estimation.

Consider the Goldschmidt method:

I'll make use of the following:
$$Q = \frac{N}{D}$$

This method works as follows:

1. Multiply N and D with a fraction F in such a way that D approaches 1.
2. As D approaches 1, N approaches Q

This method uses binary multiplication via iterative addition, which is also used in modern AMD CPUs.

Comment: Some flowcharts for variations on the 'slow' method (implemented in assembly on micros without hardware divide, but still helpful) are given in Atmel's [AVR200](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc0936.pdf) appnote.

Comment: can you please give an _illustration_ on  Goldschmidt method of division. Also the [flow chart given here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/hardware-implementation-of-division-algorithm) is an example of slow division ?

Comment: what is that method in which we have to repeatedly shift the dividend to left ?

Comment: @program-o-steve Here is a quick illustration: find 22/7 (pi approximation). First, multiply top and bottom by 0.1 to get: 2.2/0.7 Multiply again, using 1.3, giving: 2.86/0.91  Using 1.09 gives: 3.1174/0.9919   1.008 gives: 3.1423393/0.9998352  Keep going, you'll soon reach FINAL ANSWER 3.1428571/1.000000...

Comment: How do you "multiply by a fraction"? Fractions are not representable in floating point.  A fraction by definition is numerator divided by denominator, so you are left in a circular argument of still having to divide.  And how does one estimate that fraction in the first place?

Comment: How is division of negative number implemented? E.g. -3 / 7. Does it directly operate on the 2's complement representation, or it take the signed bit out during division?

Comment: Compare, Subtract and shift is a division algorithm related to the add and shift multiplication algorithm. I implemented this on a lot of early micros and it has the advantage that the time taken is data independent.

Answer (score 11):

Hardware for floating point division is part of a logic unit that also does
multiplication; there is a multiplier hardware module available.   Floating
point numbers, say A and B, are divided (forming A/B) by

1. decomposing the floating point numbers into sign (+1 or -1), mantissa ("a" and "b", and (binary integer type) exponents
2. the sign of the result is (+1) iff both signs are the same, else (-1)
3. exponents are subtracted (exponent of B subtracted from exponent of A) to
   form the exponent of the result
4. mantissas (the binary digits of the numbers) are a fixed-point binary number between 1/2 and 1; that means that the first digit after the
   binary point is '1', followed by zeroes and ones... as a first step,
   a lookup table finds the reciprocal accurate to six bits (there are only
   32 possibilities, it's a small table)
5. to begin to compute a/b,  do two multiplications
   $$ {a \over b}  = {{a * reciprocal(b)}\over b *  reciprocal(b)} $$
   and note that six-bit accuracy implies that the denominator of the result is very near 1 (to five or more binary places).
6. Now note that for very-near-one denominators, 'd', we can see that 
   defining$$ d == 1 +\epsilon   $$
   $$ d * (2-d) = ( 1+ \epsilon) \times (1-\epsilon) = 1 - \epsilon ^2 $$
   This implies that our five-bit accurate 'one' in the denominator 
   will become ten-bit accurate after one more pair of multiplications,
   twenty-bit accurate after two, and forty-bit accurate after three.  Do
   as many iterations of multiplying numerator and denominator by (2 - denominator)
   as your result precision requires.
7. The numerator, now that the denominator is exactly '1', is the mantissa of
   the result, and can be combined with the previously computed sign and exponent.
8. IEEE floating point allows some exceptions (denormalized numbers, NAN;
   those have to be handled by other logical operations.

Interestingly, the old Pentium divide bug (very newsworthy in 1994) was caused by a
printing error that made faulty reciprocal-table values for step (4).   An early paper, "A Division Method Using a Parallel Multplier", Domenico Ferrari, IEEE Trans. Electron. Comput. EC-16/224-228 (1967), describes the method, as does "The IBM System/360 Model 91: Floating-Point Execution Unit" IBM J. Res. Dev. **11**: 34-53 (1967).

Comment: Thank you, this is an amazing answer. Could you also explain a fast integer division algorithm in the same vein?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer For fast integer division omit steps 3, 7, 8.

Answer (score 3):

There are very different methods for division, depending on the numbers to be handled.  For integers, the shift-and-subtract method given by others will work fine.   For floating point numbers, however, it may be quicker to first compute the reciprocal of the denominator and then multiply that times your numerator.

Computation of the reciprocal of the denominator is not so bad; it is done by refining successive approximations.  Let g be your guess for 1/d.   For an improved guess, use g'=g(2-gd).  This converges quadratically, so you double the digits of precision on each improvement.

Example: compute the reciprocal of 3.5.

Your initial guess is 0.3.   You compute 0.3 * 3.5 = 1.15.   Your adjusted guess is 0.3 * (2 - 1.15) =  0.285.  Already pretty close!  Repeat the process, and you get 0.2857125, and a third try gets 0.2857142857.

There are some shortcuts.   In floating point, you can extract powers of ten or powers of two, depending on the number base of your machine.   And, for speed at the expense of greater memory use, you can use a pre-computed table for numbers in the range of 1 to b (where b is your number base) to get a guess that is immediately close to the required reciprocal and save one or two refinement steps.

Keep in mind that, as with multiplication and Kolmogorov's 1960 embarrassment by his student Anatoly Karatsuba, you never know when a faster or better method will be found.  Never surrender your curiosity.

Comment: Could you explain the shift and subtract algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't do iterative addition to multiply numbers - it would be really slow. In stead, there are some fast multiplication algorithms. Check out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Link-only answers are discouraged. Please summarize the information in the link.

Comment: They do. Tons of CPUs still don't have single cycle multipliers and use software mutiplication.

Comment: The question was about division not multiplication.

Comment: Goodness they don't. Wallace trees, CSA, 4:2 CSA, Han-Carlson prefix tree adders.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

All credits goes to anand kumar(the author of this book)

Comment: This doesn't really describe how division works do you think you could expand this answer